# Matconvnet disableDropout produces error: Unknown parameter 'disableDropout'

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, convolution

I'm trying to retrain a network in matconvnet, but the disableDropout option (which is set to turn on when validating) produces the error: Unknown parameter 'disableDropout' in the vl_simplenn function.

On looking into the function, I do not see this option; however there is much code on the 'net that contains this. Is disableDropout deprecated? Is there something else I need to be using? Is there some way to get it to work--as I believe it will help my accuracy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the release notes of Matconvnet beta 17 [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/about/):

> The disableDropout parameter of vl_simplenn has been replaced by a more   generic mode option that allows running in either normal mode or test mode. In the latter case, both dropout and batch normalization are bypassed. This is the same behavior of DagNN.mode.